# How to use SLDS Styles with LWC embedded in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, slds

I am embedding a custom LWC in a Visualforce page, as described in Use [Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-visualforce.html) in the LWC Docs.  It is working fine, except some styling is wrong/missing.  For example, my LWC contains a `lightning-card` that contains the rest of the component's markup, and there is no padding inside the lightning card:

[image: Screenshot of custom LWC]

Inspecting the page in the browser's dev tools, I can see that `lightning-card`'s first child is

```
<article class="slds-card" part="card">
```

And I can see that this element matches a CSS rule:

```
.slds-scope .slds-card {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: var(--slds-c-card-spacing-block-start, 
        var(--sds-c-card-spacing-block-start, 
        var(--sds-c-card-spacing-block, 0)));
    ...
```

However, each of the design tokens (CSS Vars) in the `padding-top` property (and the rest of the `padding-*` properties) is unset:
[image: image of CSS inspector]

I tried adding `lightningStylesheets="true"` to my `apex:page` tag, but I suspect the problem is that the correct stylesheet isn't being loaded into the Lightning Out iframe.  Per the docs linked above, simply extending my Aura App from "ltng:outApp" should load the SLDS styles, which I am doing.  How can I ensure that all SLDS stylesheets are being correctly loaded here?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a working version of your code showing the issue, as I have tried in my Dev org and I found no issues with the styles.